# Value of columns inOracle tables

Tags: oracle, string

I have many schemas in one oracle databse named SCHEMA1, SCHEMA2...SCHEMA999

I want to  find specific value of column named "JN_OSUSER" which is string 'Ed.Spencer'

How to find in every table, in my wholedatabase, column value which contain string value 'Ed.Spencer'?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate an SQL script with sqlplus and run that.

```
spool /tmp/get_the_ed.sql
select 'select ''' || owner || ''', ID from ' || owner
       || '.' || table_name || ' where jn_osuser = ''Ed Spencer'';'
  from all_tab_columns where column_name = 'JN_OSUSER';
spool off
start /tmp/get_the_ed
```

You need to replace "ID" by the primary key of those tables.  If that isn't always the same, you can go for rowid.